# Cockroach DB multi-tenancy IMPORT error for sql dump import

Tags: cockroachdb

I am trying to import a `sql` dump into a cockroachdb and getting the following error:

```
 IMPORT is unsupported in multi-tenancy mode
```

I have created an instance of CockroachCloud Free hosted on Google cloud Platform and have successfully connected to it form my terminal. I am trying to follow the tutorial [here](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/v20.2/migrate-from-geojson) to import spatial data (geojson) into a database I created called `SpatialData`.

After using `ogr2ogr` to convert the geojson file to a sql dump, I have hosted the sql dump on a Google Cloud Bucket and made it `public`. Here is the url for the file:

```
https://storage.googleapis.com/poi_roi/tanks.sql
```

However when I try to `IMPORT` the the data as a table in my database, I am getting the aforementioned error when I execute either of:

```
IMPORT TABLE tanks FROM PGDUMP 'https://storage.googleapis.com/poi_roi/tanks.sql';
```

OR

```
IMPORT PGDUMP('https://storage.googleapis.com/poi_roi/tanks.sql');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CockroachCloud Free is in Beta and is missing some features (the stated reason for still being in beta).

You can find more details in the [FAQ](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/cockroachcloud/free-faqs.html) which mentions restrictions in two answers. Both answers spell out the lack of support for `IMPORT` (emphasis mine):

[Limitations of CockroachCloud Free](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/cockroachcloud/free-faqs.html#what-are-the-limitations-of-cockroachcloud-free-beta):

> CockroachCloud Free is currently in beta and there are capabilities we
> are still working on enabling, such as the ability to enable backups,
> **to import data**, and no-downtime upgrades to a paid tier. If you want
> to use any of these capabilities, try a 30-day trial of
> CockroachCloud.

[Why is CockroachCLoud Free in Beta](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/cockroachcloud/free-faqs.html#why-is-cockroachcloud-free-in-beta):

> CockroachCloud Free is in beta while we work on adding core features
> like **import** and backups.

You will need to find an alternate way of loading your data such as creating the resources and inserting the data yourself.